# VUE JS in SHOPIFY: Cart properties are not updating after add to cart product

Tags: api, vue.js, shopify

How to update cart properties like cart_count, total_price, and so on in VUE JS after someone adds a product to the cart. What I am doing wrong? I have attached the code for adding products to the cart and updating minicart based on the quantity it is working fine but it is not updating other properties such as total price, total count, subtotal, and so on.

VUE CODE:

```
if (document.querySelector('.product-form')) {
  let productForm = new Vue({
    el:'.product-form',

    data(){
      return{
        form:{
          id: document.getElementById('getVariantDetails').value,
          quantity: 1
        }

      }
    },
    methods:{
      addToCart(){
        axios.post('/cart/add.js', this.form )
        .then( (response) => {

          // add data to mini cart object
          // check if product already exist
          let found = store.state.cartData[0].items.find(product => product.variant_id == response.data.variant_id);
          if(found){
            found.quantity += parseInt(this.form.quantity);
            // you can reset the quanity back to 1 if you want
            // this.form.quantity = 1;
          }else{
            // add item at the start of array
            store.state.cartData[0].items.unshift(response.data);
          }
          this.openMiniCart();

        })
        .catch( (error) =>  {
          console.log(error);
        });
      },

      openMiniCart(){
          // open mini cart
          $('#minicart-modal').addClass('active');
      }
    }
  });
}
if (document.querySelector('.minicart-app')) {
  let MiniCart = new Vue({
    el:'.minicart-app',
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],

    data(){
      return{
        cartData: store.state.cartData
      }
    },
    computed: {
      cart(){
        return this.cartData[0];
      }
    },
    created(){
      // mini cart is on every page, that's why, we cal it once here
      store.getCart();
    },
    methods:{
      // Remove item from cart
      remove(item){
        let found = this.cart.items.find(product => product.variant_id == item.variant_id);
        if(found){
          this.$delete(this.cart.items, this.cart.items.indexOf(found));
          axios.post('/cart/update.js', 'updates['+item.id+']=0');
        }
      },
      // Increment item by 1
      increment(item){
        let found = this.cart.items.find(product => product.variant_id == item.variant_id);
        if (found) {
          this.updateCart(found, 1);
        }
      },
      // Decrement item by 1
      decrement(item){
        let found = this.cart.items.find(product => product.variant_id == item.variant_id);
        if (found) {

          if (item.quantity > 0) {
            this.updateCart(found, -1 );
          }
        }
      },
      updateCart(item, quantity){
        let q = quantity + item.quantity;

        let data = {
          quantity: q,
          id: item.key
        }

        if (q < 1) {
          this.remove(item);
        }

        axios.post('/cart/change.js', data )
        .then( (response) => {

          // Find the current item and new item to compare the quanity
          let currentItem = this.cartData[0].items.find(product => product.variant_id == item.variant_id);
          let newItem = response.data.items.find(product => product.variant_id == item.variant_id);

          // If item exist
          if (currentItem) {
            // check if item quantity changed. Only change.js can detect this on response
            if(quantity > 0 && currentItem.quantity == newItem.quantity){

            }else{
              // add one to current item
              currentItem.quantity += quantity;
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    },
  });   
}
```

Template file: (header.liquid)

```
    <template v-if="cart">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="cart_icon" data-cart-text="{{ 'layout.general.cart' | t }}" data-links-toggle="#minicart-modal">
        <i class="icon"><img src="{{ 'bag.png' | file_img_url }}" /></i>
        <template v-if="cart.item_count"><span class="cart_count">${ cart.item_count }</span></template>
      </a>
      {% include 'links-hover' %}
    </template>
```

[Click to see the image (Quantity is not updating reactivity on runtime)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZE3V.png)

Comment: `total_price` is not shown anywhere, and `cart.item_count` is missing from the code

Comment: I am new to vue.js would you guide how can I add this?